# how to set "rich text editor " to be the default on mediawiki with wysiwig extension

Tags: wysiwyg, mediawiki

using mediawiki 2.0 and a skin which is derived from Monobook, I am using the Wysiwig extension, when people edit they don't see the Rich Text by default, they have to click "SHOW RICH TEXT EDITOR"

Is there anyway to set this as the default?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a link with the problem you stated - I haven't tested it, though.

Try by adding the following lines to your *LocalSettings.php* file.

`$wgDefaultUserOptions['riched_use_toggle'] = 0; 
$wgDefaultUserOptions['riched_start_disabled'] = 0; 
$wgDefaultUserOptions['riched_use_popup'] = 0; $wgDefaultUserOptions['riched_toggle_remember_state'] = 1;`

Info taken from [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread%3aExtension_talk%3aWYSIWYG/Set_WYSIWYG_rich_text_editor_as_default_for_new_users_in_MediaWiki_1.17.x).